# Sonarqube scanner error for deletion of .sonartmp file with "DirectoryNotEmptyException"

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonarscanner

In the Virtual Machine, am doing the sonarqube analysis using "*SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe*" for the dotnet solution. During the end step analysis of code completes & zipped it. but while uploading the zip content to the sonar server, it throws the "java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException" exception & uploading fails.

***Details***

**SonarQube :** v6.7.2

**Sonarscanner :** v3.1.0.1141

**OS :** Windows 7 (64 bit)

I have also tried setting the property "sonar.ws.timeout=9000" in sonar-scanner.properties file to increase time. It also not worked.

The error message is:

````
03:46:53.875 INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 10624ms, zip size=3 MB
03:46:53.876 INFO: Analysis report generated in ProjWksp\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\scanner-report
03:46:53.876 DEBUG: Upload report
03:47:03.997 ERROR: Failed to delete temp folder
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: ProjWksp\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\.sonartmp
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.internal.DefaultTempFolder$DeleteRecursivelyFileVisitor.postVisitDirectory(DefaultTempFolder.java:121)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.internal.DefaultTempFolder$DeleteRecursivelyFileVisitor.postVisitDirectory(DefaultTempFolder.java:110)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.internal.DefaultTempFolder.clean(DefaultTempFolder.java:97)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.internal.DefaultTempFolder.stop(DefaultTempFolder.java:106)
        at org.sonar.scanner.analysis.AnalysisTempFolderProvider.stop(AnalysisTempFolderProvider.java:61)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stopAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1048)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stop(DefaultPicoContainer.java:803)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentContainer.java:164)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:111)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

03:47:04.237 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
03:47:04.245 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
03:47:04.245 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
03:47:04.246 INFO: Total time: 1:18.489s
03:47:04.376 INFO: Final Memory: 17M/512M
03:47:04.381 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
03:47:04.382 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
03:47:04.382 ERROR: Fail to request http://sonarqube:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.projectkey52.cs&projectName=SampleProj
03:47:04.383 ERROR: Caused by: timeout
03:47:04.386 ERROR: Caused by: Socket closed
03:47:04.389 ERROR:
03:47:04.389 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. 
Process returned exit code 1
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
03:47:04.636  Creating a summary markdown file...
03:47:04.667  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1```
````